# Thread doesn't close with c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a little problem here.

I start a thread to show time on windows form, but when I close, the handler " onclosed " or " onclosing " dont work Application.Exit();

the thread keeps running.

the code:

```
    private void frm_agenda_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(disparar_time));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void disparar_time()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            time(lbl_time);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public delegate void delegade_time(Label lbl);
    private void time(Label lbl)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                Invoke(new delegade_time(time), lbl_time);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                lbl.Text = date.ToLongDateString() + " " + date.ToLongTimeString();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void frm_agenda_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ExitThread();
    }
```

Comment: ExitThead() and Exit() dont stop the application that keep runing, i dont have idea how solve it.

Comment: One way is to introduce a bool variable, set it to true, then test on that rather than `true` in `while(true)` in your thread method. Then set it to `false` when you are shutting down, thus causing the thread to terminate itself.

Comment: cool!!! its worked very well, the thread only close when end the code, thanks thanks thanks :)

Comment: Grant Winney thanks its worked too, thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep your thread variable in a place where you can access it later to stop the thread. Or you need an object to syncronize the two threads. Or (and I think that would be the best option) you leave threading alone for a while and use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to display the time.

Comment: interesting, ok, i want use thread because i'm learning how control, so, you can tell me how i can control the thread after? i create a variable " id " to be acessible in any method, and used " id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; " before enter in the loop, now, how i can control on formclosing?

Comment: and if possible, do you can give me some idea how i can use a object to control the threads?

Answer (score 1):

`Application.ExitThread();` simply tells the main message loop to stop processing.  But the thread you create is an entirely separate thread from the main message loop.  It's also a foreground thread, and since there is still a foreground thread running the application won't end.

While there are several ways you could address this and stop the other thread from executing, you shouldn't even do that.  You're not using the right tool for the job in the first place.  Rather than creating a thread just so that it can spend 99.99% of it's time sleeping for a set interval of time, just use a `Timer` instead.  It can run some code (and if you use the forms timer, even run that code in the main thread for you) in a set interval.  It will be easier for you to work with, and won't result in the creation of any new threads that need to be closed or that could keep the application running.